# How to cast string to uint32 luajit ffi

Tags: casting, lua, ffi, unpack, luajit

Consider that `str` is a binary string which contains an unsigned int 32 at position 13.

I tried this:

```lua
local value = ffi.cast("uint32_t", ffi.new("char[4]", str:sub(13,16)))
```

However, the data returned is a "cdata" of type unsigned int and I don't now how to get the actual value (the Int)

Comment: `tonumber(cdata)`

Comment: But your expression calculates the address of the string instead of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I agree with Egor Skriptunoffs answer. For a more generalized aproach (and maybe soemwhat overkill for this particular case) one could use a union type

```
local ffi = require 'ffi'

local union_type = ffi.typeof [[
  union {
    char bytes[4];
    uint32_t integer;
  }
]]

local union = union_type { bytes = 'abcd' }

print(string.format('0x%x', union.integer))
```

note that you need to worry about endianness here; you can confirm your systems endianness with `ffi.abi('le')` or `ffi.abi('be')`. If you're getting your string from somewhere else (like over the network), its endianness is most likely documented somewhere.

Suppose you want to interpret the string fromt he above example (`abcd`) as big endian; then you could do this

```
local union do
  if ffi.abi('le') then
    union = union_type { bytes = ('abcd'):reverse() }
  else
    union = union_type { bytes = 'abcd' }
  end
end
```

If the system is little endian, reverse the string. Otherwise leave it as is.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing converts cdata array into Lua number

```
local value = ffi.cast("uint32_t*", ffi.new("const char*", str:sub(13,16)))[0]
```